# Update dynamically if checked update cek=1 or cek=0 if unchecked

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

```html
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th nowrap>TGL</th>
          <th>CEK</th>
          <th>TITEL</th>
          <th>VAL</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>01.12.19</td>
          <td nowrap><input type='checkbox' name='cek' /></td>
          <td nowrap>Test 1</td>
          <td nowrap>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>02.12.19</td>
          <td nowrap><input type='checkbox' name='cek' /></td>
          <td nowrap>Test 2</td>
          <td nowrap>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>03.12.19</td>
          <td nowrap><input type='checkbox' name='cek' /></td>
          <td nowrap>Test 3</td>
          <td nowrap>3</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody
```

Update mysqli table with it code only if checked, I want sort unchecked so I can update my fields on table like flag=1 or flag=0 dynamicaly based on checked or unchecked:

```
function checked_pkb(f) {
  var txsql=$("#sql_text").val();
  $(".ceks").text("refresh ...");
  var cek=[];
  $('.get_value').each(function(){
   if($(this).is(":checked")){
     cek.push($(this).val());
   }    
 });
  cek=cek.toString();
  $.ajax({
   url:"update.php",
   method:"POST",
   data:{cek:cek,f:f},
   success:function(data){
   alert(data);
   }
  })

 }
```

on php

```
$pathme = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/db_/db.php";
include($pathme);
if(isset($_POST['cek'])){
$q="update t1 set fk=".$_POST['f']." where t1_id IN (".$_POST['cek'].")";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$q);
echo $q;
}
```

on code above only update for value is checked, but we have toggle 0 or 1, if checked then checked(1) or if unchecked then unchecked(0)
on table something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `pkb` (
 `pkb_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `tgl_pkb` date DEFAULT NULL,
 `desc` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
 `status` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 PRIMARY KEY (`pkb_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6051 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

the value of status will be 0 or 1 based on checked or unchecked.
something like this, it is set value static as (0)  with button onclick:

```
<button onclick='c_tabel(0)' class='btn btn-success btn-md rad'>checked</button>
```

but what I mean is dynamic set 0 or 1 if checked or unchecked

Answer (score 0):

cek.push($(this).val()); it will give you array format example:[1,2,3],you cannot use array in Sql IN Operator 
Instead of array create string like example : 1,2,3

Comment: something like this, if you checked then php updated for field status=1, if you unchecked then php update status=0. if 0 then 1 or if 1 then 0

Comment: use the same QUERY with NOT IN operator and opposite of flag.if you want update all rows other than checked ones.

Answer (score 0):

```
//html input field
<input class="pull-right" id="name" type="checkbox" value="1">
// javascript
$("input[id='name']").change(function() 
        {   
            var name= $(this).prop('checked');
            var id=$('#id').val();
            if(access_value){
            $.ajax(
                    {
                        type:'POST',
                        url:'../php/update/update_flag_one.php',
                        data: {id:id},
                        success:function(html)
                        {
                            alert("Status Update Successfuly");
                             location.reload();
                        }
                    });

        }
            else{
                $.ajax(
                    {
                        type:'POST',
                        url:'../php/update/update_flag_zero.php',
                        data: {id:id},
                        success:function(html)
                        {
                            alert("Status Update Successfuly");
                             location.reload();                 
                        }
                    });
            }
        });

//update_flag_one.php
<?php
session_start();
include '../../dbconnect/dbconnect.php';
$id =  $_POST['id'];
$query = "UPDATE flag_table SET flag=1 WHERE id = '$id'";
if(mysqli_query($conn, $query))
{
 location.reload();
}
?>

//update_flag_zero.php
<?php
session_start();
include '../../dbconnect/dbconnect.php';
$id =  $_POST['id'];
$query = "UPDATE flag_table SET flag=0 WHERE id = '$id'";
if(mysqli_query($conn, $query))
{
 location.reload();
}
?>
```

Comment: it is auto respond onchange, it can be multiple or update with multi

Comment: yes, when the checkbox is pressed it automatically changes